# ECONNRESET and SOCKET HANG UP errors when trying to send Requests to Google API with node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I´m using **Google´s node.js API Library** to send product data to google merchant center.
In about 30% of the requests i get the following errors:

- request to https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/products/batch failed, reason: **socket hang up**
- request to https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/products/batch failed, reason: **read ECONNRESET**

I think the reason might be that the requests are send to fast and the quota limits of the API are hit.
Which method can I use to limit the number of requests to the API? I´ve tried

```
setTimeout(() => { null }, 3000);
```

every time before the API request is send, but it looks like it doesn´t change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here´s the solution to that issue. I´ve added a wait method which returns a Promise.

```js
while((batchOffset + batchSize)  <= products.length) {

      const entries = [];
      const productsBatch = products.slice(batchOffset, (batchOffset+batchSize));

      // Wait between API calls to avoid hitting Google API quota limits 
      await this.wait(100);

      // Send a batch of n products to Google content API
      contentApi.products.custombatch(
        {
          requestBody: {
            entries: entries,
          },
        },
        (err, res) => {
          // handle err and response
          if (err !== null || res.status !== 200) {
            this.logger.log(
              'error',
              '...'
            );
          } else {
            this.logger.log(
              'info',
              '...',
            );
          }
        },
      );

      batchOffset+=batchSize;

}


......

private wait(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
  }
```